# Array is referred to as object in one function which causes error when using formatter in Angular Formly

Tags: angular, angular-forms, angular-formly

In Fromly.js file we have a function called `addFormatters`.

We are using `var ctrl = scope.fc;`

Actually `scope.fc` is an array as I can see in the whole formly.js file but inside the above function it's trying to retrieve values as Object instead of array.

```
var value = ctrl.$modelValue;

ctrl.$formatters.forEach(function (formatter) {
     value = formatter(value);
});

ctrl.$setViewValue(value);
ctrl.$render();
ctrl.$setPristine();
```

The above assigned value has to be change to `ctrl = scope.fc || scope.fc[0]` so that it doesn't throw undefined error when using formatters.

Comment: there is no question here.

Comment: no i was able to find the answer but wanted angular-formly to update it so posted it here